# DBus-Server in Java?

Tags: java, dbus

Is there a server implementation of [DBus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) for Java? There's a [lib](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/) for clients and services (not servers).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like since you originally asked your question, the library has gained support for what you ask for, at least the [DBusDaemon](http://dbus-java.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.8-2/DBusDaemon_8java_source.html) source contains a [DBusServer](http://dbus-java.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.8-2/classorg_1_1freedesktop_1_1dbus_1_1bin_1_1DBusDaemon_1_1DBusServer.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following why it would be necessary to have a language specific implementation of the server.  I don't get the impression that more then one instance of DBus is intended to run in parallel on a server, so whichever events you public/subscribe to is all client side.  If it's all client side that's all in java, and that's all you need to interact with.  Nothing should be calling directly into the server code, so why would you need a java implementation of the server?

Comment: Start with an environment where _all there is_ is a JVM.  No one else has started a dbus server for you.  You want to use it for your own purposes.  Now do you see why it might be interesting?